# aggregate with function rosnerTest

Tags: r, envstats

I get an error

> "Error in if (any(outlier)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
>   when I try to use the rosnerTest, from the package EnvStats.

```
out1 <- aggregate(x = df$Price, by = list(df$Item), FUN = rosnerTest)
```

I'm trying to use the aggregate function in place of using for loop to do the rosner test because my data has over 14 million records with about 3 million unique items.

Comment: what package is `rosnerTest` found in?

Answer (score 0):

Try `tapply` instead:

`out1 <- tapply(df$Price, df$Item, rosnerTest)`

Comment: I tried tapply also and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a while ago, but maybe it still helps someone:

I got the same error because I had no outliers in some rows (e.g. all values were the same).
In a for loop, you can use the `try()` function to ignore these errors and the loop will continue with the next row.